# validation length seems not working in migration ruby on rails and sqlite database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem .When I run the migration with the following constraints and then go to the Sqlite database those constraints haven't efect in the sqlite database

not_null worked perfect but length not ?

Ruby On Rails 3.2

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user_name, :null=>false, :length => 20
      t.string :password, :null=>false
      t.string :email, :null=>false, :length => 30
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Sqlite

```
-- Describe USERS
CREATE TABLE users (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "user_name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "password" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "email" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "created_at" DATETIME NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: You know that SQLite maps `varchar(n)` to `text`, right? The `n` is ignored at the database level even though the table definition will track it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That options is named `limit` not `length`. Try this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user_name, :null => false, :limit => 20
      t.string :password,  :null => false
      t.string :email,     :null => false, :limit => 30
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```